# Ubuntu on WSL looks for npm in Windows filesystem instead

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed Node and npm on Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2. Node runs fine. However, when typing `npm` on the command line, it appears to be loading the npm which is in `/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs`. Running `npm -v` will result in:

```
-bash: /mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

`which npm` shows that my npm is `/usr/bin/npm`.

`/usr/bin` is in my `PATH` variable above `/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs`. Output of `process.env.PATH.split(":")` is:

```
[ '/usr/local/sbin',
  '/usr/local/bin',
  '/usr/sbin',
  '/usr/bin',
  '/sbin',
  '/bin',
  ...
  '/mnt/c/Python27',
  '/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/',
  ...
]
```

Why is it running npm from the wrong location and how do I fix this?

Comment: I fixed it by editing out that Windows path in .bashrc. But I am curious why `/usr/bin` isn't selected for npm.